# Multiple federation policies in RabbitMQ

Tags: rabbitmq, message-queue

I have a number of RabbitMQ servers arranged effectively in a star topology. I need to federate a different exchange bi-directionally between the central hub server and each of the outer servers. Configuration of the outer servers isn't problematic, but although the exchanges are different the hub doesn't want to accept more than one federation policy.

Defining multiple upstreams and upstream sets works as expected:

```
$ rabbitmqctl list_parameters
Listing runtime parameters ...
federation-upstream-set leaf1      [{"upstream":"leaf1-1"}]
federation-upstream-set leaf2 [{"upstream":"leaf2-1"}]
federation-upstream     leaf2-1      {"uri":"--snipped--","expires":3600000}
federation-upstream     leaf1-1   {"uri":"--snipped--","expires":3600000}
...done.
```

The first federation policy applies as expected:

```
$ rabbitmqctl set_policy --apply-to exchanges federate-me "^leaf1$" '{"federation-upstream-set":"leaf1"}'
Setting policy "federate-me" for pattern "^leaf1$" to "{\"federation-upstream-set\":\"leaf1\"}" with priority "0" ...
...done.
$ rabbitmqctl list_policies
Listing policies ...
/       federate-me     exchanges       ^leaf1$        {"federation-upstream-set":"leaf1"}   0
...done.
```

But as soon as I try to specify a second federation policy, it simply replaces the first one:

```
$ rabbitmqctl set_policy --apply-to exchanges federate-me "^leaf2$" '{"federation-upstream-set":"leaf2"}'
Setting policy "federate-me" for pattern "^leaf2$" to "{\"federation-upstream-set\":\"leaf2\"}" with priority "0" ...
...done.
$ rabbitmqctl list_policies
Listing policies ...
/       federate-me     exchanges       ^leaf2$        {"federation-upstream-set":"leaf2"}   0
...done.
```

It doesn't matter if I specify different priorities for the two policies, either; whatever I do, only the single most recently entered federation policy is listed. I know that only a single policy can apply to each exchange, but the exchange specification for each policy here is different, and moreover the documentation suggests that the policy with the highest priority should win in the event that there are multiple matching policies.

Can anyone help?

Comment: We added a note in our docs to mention that federate-me is just a name you can provide to your policy https://www.rabbitmq.com/federation.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to specify unique name for each policy you want to add. Setting different policy with existent name will just override existent policy with that name.

Comment: Just commenting in case someone else makes the mistake I did: "federate-me" in the various examples available isn't a magic token, it's an arbitrary name for the policy.

Comment: We added a note in our docs to mention that federate-me is just a name you can provide to your policy http://www.rabbitmq.com/federation.html